# How can I provide a user with an unsigned transaction that, when signed, sends their ether/ERC-20 tokens to another address?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, tokens, transfer

I would like to create a dapp that provides an invoice like work flow. For example: Alice would like to buy 1 apple from Bob for 2DAI. How can Bob programmatically provide Alice a way to send the 2DAI? Does this need to be programmed via smart contract or can this be accomplished another way?

Answer (score 0):

- Well there ways to that, like if you know(you trust him/her for paying first) the receiver can share its public key to the sender then he/she send the token to that address.
- but if you don't know the sender then here takes place an smart contract which work on set of rules were if both agrees the the receiver will receive the dai and in exchange he will send apple to him/her.

It can be an example, but there is an issue here in second point, if the product is an offline stuff(means and asset or any thing or object) it will be hard to track that object as it is not connect with the online world. but if its an nft or any think like that then it works fine